# open a popup window in asp.net without showing url of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a linkbutton on asp.net page and the url of the page it opens upon clicking is created dynamically. 
How do I hide the url of the popup page displayed from displating in the address bar?  any other options than using the link button? 
Code:

```
lnkTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + HttpContext.Current.Session["AttachmentURL"] + "','toolbar=no,titlebar=no,location=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,status=no,directories=no');");
```

This popup  opens an attachment stored in the database using the url. Therefore the url is to be hidden from users.

Comment: Be aware that not showing the URL in a browser in no way hides it from the browser or from the user.

Comment: I don't understand how the URL opening an attachment stored in the database leads to the URL needing to be hidden from the users. If you think not displaying the URL would be a suitable replacement for proper security, that is very wrong. If the request is being made by the client, the client needs the URL. If the client has the URL, the end user has the URL. What is your actual concern? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I do something similar to handle PDF attachments. Look into generic handler, `.ashx` files.  the `HttpContext` can be passed to the handler class server side granting you access to the session variables effectively hiding the DB AttachmentURL.  The call would look something like `window.open('YourHandlerName.ashx')`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I hide the url of the popup page displayed from displating in the address bar?

You can't in most modern browsers, for  good security reasons

> This popup opens an attachment stored in the database using the url. Therefore the url is to be hidden from users.

Security by obscurity in this context is nonsensical. The URL of your page will show in the developer tools as soon as it loads, hiding nothing

Change things up so your url doesn't bear sensitive info